# Unable to install the SDK tools, finish button is disabled

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I am trying to install the SDK tools for Android, i clicked on "Accept" but finish button is disable, how to get out from this problem?

**here is the snap of what i am doing!**

[image]

Comment: Go to the * licence and accept it, scroll down to the end if the accept option is not avaliable

Comment: @javdromero there is no option of accept except this one, i scrolled down till end.

Comment: Did you check every single one? Also as any installer may bug, try to start it again

Comment: I tried to install 2 parallel, it works, all tools installing at once create this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**
Try to install 2 tools in parallel, not more than 2, if u try to install more than 2 tools this will create this problem.

Comment: This is not the right answer. You have just to accept the license for every component, even for those you don't need to install.

Answer (score 9):

You need to accept the license agreement for each and every License displayed on the screen. Once all license agreement is accepted it will display in bold and the Finish button will be enabled.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. The wizard UX is not self explanatory.

Answer (score 3):

[image]
**Solution is here;**

1. Firstly, you should have to collapse all the expanded tabs.
2. Secondly, you have click on every tab.
3. Thirdly, every clickable tab should be accept the **terms and conditions**.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the possible reason is that you have to wait because packages are getting download. Once the packages downloaded then you will be able to click on finish button (only a guess, it might be the possible reason. I solved the problem by "manually downloading" the sdk using terminal which I explained below).
But I had a bad internet connection, so, my computer was just get stucked. And I have to download them one by one on my compter.

For manual installation of SDK watch the following video -

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c7_JxGX8oxc

At the end you have to add "Android SDK" in the "Android Studio" for that do the following -

1. Open android studio
2. Click on "Customize" on top left corner
3. Select "all setting..."
4. Go to "Appearance & Behavior" -> "System Settings" -> "Android SDK"
5. Now, find this line -
   Android SDK Location:                                              Edit    Optimize disk space
6. Click on "Edit"
7. It will open an popup window, it will again ask for "Android SDK Location:" (or it will automatically sense it), to fill the location click on "folder icon", locate downloaded android SDK folder. It will sense the recent available updates, slect them if you want to download them
8. Then keep clicking on "Next" untill it start downloading packages
9. Once all stuff is done, "THE FINISH BUTTON WILL GET HIGHLIGHT, YOU CAN CLICK IT NOW, AND BE HAPPY, THERE IS NOTHING WORNG WITH YOUR LUCK "

By the way, I just started Android Development. I am pure noob. So, if something is wrong feel free to correct me :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to scroll down to the end of the license text and then click on "Accept", **for all the root items** in the right column.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, then I clicked on all the sdk options and checked whether all were accepted or not. The last one was not accepted, so I accepted it and the finish button was enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You have just to accept the license for every component, even for those you don't need to install

Answer (score 0):

If you select accept for each license on the left, the problem may be solved. This method worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You have to Accept the terms & Conditions for all Licenses displayed on the left pane. Click on each license and click Accept radio button.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You need to  accept the terms & Conditions for all Licenses displayed on the left panel. Click on each license and click Accept radio button.

Check the arrow in given image and accept all the boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Each license tab must be clicked individually and accepted.

This [video](https://youtu.be/_n3SsBl8EWY) will show you how to fix this issue.

Comment: please expand. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587